# Is it possible to work on multiple bug fixes using Eclipse & SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, clearcase

With Clearcase I can create multiple views and work on 3-4 defects simultaneously.  Is it possible to work in a similar manner without having multiple instances of svn checkouts and mulitple instances of Eclipse IDE?  What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need multiple svn workspaces,  like you need multiple ClearCase snapshot view.
(only multiple *dynamic* views allow you to avoid multiple copies on your disk, because of the particular nature of the dynamic view)

And you would need multiple Eclipse workspaces since you cannot import the same project twice in a single Eclipse workspace, whatever the source control tool you are using.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple workspaces in the same Eclipse IDE and switch between them via a keystroke combination?

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan you can check if you can assign a key shortcut to http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-workspaceswitch.htm . But a workspace switch always involve Eclipse being closed/reopened, which isn't very practical. And cleaning old workspaces isn't easy (http://www.bingshui.org/tech/eclipse-switch-workspace-list/)

Comment: You can checkout the same project multiple times in the same workspace, been doing this for years to maintain different branches in a single workspace without restarting eclipse.

Comment: @vinnyjames interesting, but you have to rename the project (store din the `.project`file), don't you? One Eclipse workspace cannot reference the same project *name* multiple time, right?

Comment: Yeah when you checkout there's an option to rename it (even if the .project file already exists in the repo)